# SQL query efficiency when using PHP classes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, class, oop

I've been programming in PHP for many years, however only recently started programming with classes. I have the following - basic - user class as follows:

```
<?php
/* The class for constructing any user's information
 */

    class User {

        protected $userId, $email, $userGroup;

        protected function getEmail() {
            return $this->email;
        }

        protected function getUserId() {
            return $this->userId;
        }

        protected function getUserGroup() {
            return $this->userId;
        }


        public function __construct($userId='') {
            if($userId) {
                $select = mysql_query("SELECT userId, email, user_group FROM user WHERE userId = '$userId'");
                while($user==mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
                $this->email = $user[email];
                    $this->userId = $userId;
                    $this->userGroup = $user[user_group];
                }
            }
        }

}?>
```

So I understand I can do the following

```
<?php
$user = new User($userId);
echo $user->getEmail();
?>
```

To display the user's email address for a given userId. What I'd like to know is, what would be the best way -  using OOP - to display, say, 40 user's emails. Obviously creating 40 user objects would be silly as that's 40 SQL queries. Would you simply make a "users" class that was used for returning an array of multiple users, after doing an SQL given various parameters?

Ie

```
<?php
$getUsers = new Users('Tom');
// create 'Users' object where name is 'Tom'
print_r($users);
// prints the returned array of users?
?>
```

Thanks for your help. Hopefully this is clear.

Comment: Where does `$userID` normally come from? If it's from an external source, you're prone to SQL injection. Please switch to prepared statements to prevent that. BTW, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Hi Marcel. I will add security features to my SQL at a later stage - this is just a basic early code whilst I clear up my initial question in my head. Thanks for pointing out about mysql_*  - I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @Tom : have look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). With PDO u can cast a recordset to an array of ex. User. This way u only need 1 SQL and u get 40users in return

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do it something like this (using another class):

```
class UserRepository {
    public function getByName($name) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT userId, email, user_group FROM user WHERE name = '$name'");

        $users = [];

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $user = new User;
            $user->email     = $row['email'];
            $user->userId    = $row['userId'];
            $user->userGroup = $row['user_group'];

            $users[] = $user;
        }

        return $users;
    }
}
```

**Addition:**
The following example gives a good idea on how you can make the classes more testable and easy to modify in the future should they need to be:

**UserRepositoryInterface**

```
interface UserRepositoryInterface {
    public function getByName($name);
    public function getByUserId($id);
}
```

**MySqliUserRepository**

```
class MySqliUserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface {
    public function getByName($name) {
        // Get by name using mysqli methods here
    }

    public function getByUserId($id) {
        // Get by user id using mysqli methods here
    }
}
```

**PDOUserRepository**

```
class PDOUserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface {
    public function getByName($name) {
        // Get by name using PDO methods here
    }

    public function getByUserId($id) {
        // Get by user id using PDO methods here
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class Foo {

    protected $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository) {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function bar() {
        $user = $this->userRepository->getByUserId(10);
    }
}
```

**Regarding use of `mysql_`**

It may not be exactly how you do it but it'll give you an idea. Also `mysql_` is depreciated so its best to use `mysqli_` or `PDO` (my personal recommendation). `PDO` is also much more OOP friendly.

`PDO`: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

`mysqli_`: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

**Update:**

Your individual user class would simply contain information relating to the user. The user class shouldn't contain any way to retrieve a user, that is the job of the repository. So if you want to retrieve 1 user, instead of doing in the `User` `__construct` as you currently do, add a method to the `UserRepository` that looks something like this:

```
public function getByUserId($id) {
    // Select user from db, check only 1 exists, make user object, return.
}
```

Comment: @DarkBee I've explained that its depreciated and recommended alternatives, he says he just wants to get an idea on how to do it and used `mysql_` in his original question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would you still have an individual user class as well though, for individual user specific things? For example, $user->hasAccess($page);  or something like that? Or would you simply have a method on this e.g  checkUserAccess($userId, $page);  ? Thanks for your help

Comment: So to clarify. You would have something like $userRepository = new UserRepository(); $user = $userRepository->getByUserId('41'); echo $user->getEmail(); ? Cheers

Comment: @TomMac Yes, that's how I would do it, but obviously if the id is an integer it'd look like: `$user = $userRepository->getByUserId(41);`.

Comment: @TomMac I've updated my answer again and added a little more information on how I use dependency injection so it is easy to test my repositories.

Comment: @DarkBee, just because ext/mysql is deprecated doesn't mean projects currently using it will run out and rewrite all their code. It just means *new* projects should avoid using it. It's reasonable for Adam to give an answer using the same API that the OP used. Your downvote is unwarranted.

Comment: @BillKarwin, this is not an existing project. So there is no need to use older functions when starting from scratch. My two cents... Showing how its not done is plain bad.

Answer (score 1):

I try to separate my data objects from the DB stuff. In your case, I'd make the following arrangements:

- An instance of the `User` class represents an individual user, either in DB or not. The constructor does not retrieve anything from DB, it just populates class properties.
- For users not in DB (e.g., a newly created user) the `userId` property is `NULL` (not `''`).
- Methods that do DB stuff expect a database interface (or at least an object) as argument:

  ```
  public function save(PDO $pdo){
  }
  ```
- There're static methods to fetch stuff from DB where a class instance does not make sense yet; they return either a `User` instance or a `User` collection:

  ```
  public static function fetchById(PDO $pdo, $id){
  }

  public static function fetchAll(PDO $pdo){
  }
  ```
- When it makes sense, I write a private method to share common code:

  ```
  private static function fetch(PDO $pdo, array $filter=array()){
      $sql = 'SELECT id, email, group
           FROM user' . PHP_EOL;
      $params = array();

     if( isset($filter['id']) ){
         $sql .= 'WHERE id=:id';
         $params['id'] = $filter['id'];
     }

     //...
  }

  public static function fetchById(PDO $pdo, $id){
      $data = self::fetch($pdo, array('id' => $id));
      if( empty($data) ){
          return NULL;
      }else{
          reset($data);
          return curren($data);
      }
  }

  public static function fetchAll(PDO $pdo){
      return self::fetch($pdo);
  }
  ```
- The *`User` collection* I've mentioned can as simple as an array of `User` instances, or as elaborate as your own generics implementation.

This way, a typical script looks like this:

```
// Fetch my details
$me = User::fetchById(1);

// Create a new user
$you = new User(NULL, 'Joe', 'Guests');
$you->save($pdo);
$message = sprintf('User created with ID=%d', $you->userId);
```

Comment: So are your fetch methods being housed under the User class? With this, if you did $me=User::fetchById(1); could you then say echo $me->userId; ? Would you need to define the constructors still? Thanks

Comment: @Tom - #1 and #2: correct. #3: Constructor is not mandatory but lack of one would turn `$you = new User(NULL, 'Joe', 'Guests');` into 4 lines of code. Also, please note you'll make heavy use of the constructor within the `fetch...` methods. My criterion is to define important/mandatory properties in the constructor and assign additional secondary properties somewhere else (e.g., with a setter function) but I guess the important bit is to be coherent.

Comment: I think I've got it. Does this mean if you did $users = User::fetchAll();, would this then mean $users is an array of User objects. ie, echo $user[0]->userId; would echo the first user's userId? Thanks again

Comment: Exactly. Also, note that Adam's `UserRepository` is a more sophisticated solution to this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the construct to retrieve a user, you could use methods to insert/retrieve users instead.

You can create methods to insert new users, update a particular user, retrieve one particular user or retrieve all (with conditions) in an array of users' objects, etc